# Требования Google к фоновому местоположению

Tags: android, google-play, apk

Внедрил к себе в программу отображение стационарных камер по геометкам, для работы этой функции подключил доступ к фоновому определению местоположения. Однако Google не хочет принимать мой apk и пишет след.ответ:

> Функция не соответствует требованиям для доступа к фоновому местоположению
> Основываясь на нашем обзоре, ваша заявленная функция не соответствует требованиям для доступа к фоновому местоположению.
>
> Пожалуйста, удалите запрошенное разрешение на фоновое местоположение и отправьте обновление в свое приложение. При объявлении функции для доступа к фоновому местоположению, пожалуйста, обратите внимание на следующее:
> Выбранная вами функция должна обеспечивать четкую ценность для пользователя и быть важной для основной функциональности или основной цели приложения. Без этой основной функции приложение “сломано” или становится непригодным для использования.
> Вам также следует подумать, будут ли пользователи ожидать, что приложение будет получать доступ к их местоположению в фоновом режиме, и сможете ли вы обеспечить тот же опыт без доступа к местоположению в фоновом режиме.

С чего он решил, представляет ли эта функция ценность или нет? Что сделать, что бы они приняли исправление? Техподдержка у них дубовая.
Все данные по заполнению информации на странице разработчика заполнил.

Comment: Если вы отображаете геометки в приложении, когда оно активно, то фоновое местоположение вам не нужно

Comment: Приложение может быть свёрнуто, но данные должны появляться

Comment: Может помочь видео, в котором есть, во-первых, алерт с запросом на фоновую геолокацию с подробным описанием зачем эта функция нужна, именно бизнес-функция, например, фитнес-трек или трек передвижения курьеров.... Во-вторых, отображение где полученные в фоне данные пользователь может увидеть в приложении (например где-то карта открывается и там трек передвижений виден).
И самый простой вариант, убрать разрешение, опубликовать приложение без фоновой геолокации, а потом пытаться обновить приложение и вести переписку до положительного результата.